# Why do elliptical galaxies not have large proportion of blue stars?

Tags: astrophysics, stars, gas, galaxies, stellar-evolution

In an article it was given that elliptical galaxies are also formed when a spiral galaxy experiences continuous star burst thus depleting it's gas. So if this is correct than why do elliptical galaxies not have many blue stars since star burst must produce lots of new stars?

Comment: Would you cite the article? I feel this is a question for Astronomy SE instead.

Comment: [Galaxies can die?!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pD6D3u7g_cA&t=509s)

Answer (score 3):

Blue or [O-type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O-type_star) stars are necessarily young stars. Their high temperature leads to rapid hydrogen burning and within 10 million years or so they will either go supernova or cool down and change colour.

If large scale star formation in a galaxy ceased more than 10 million years ago (because, for example, the interstellar gas necessary for new star formation has been depleted) then the proportion of blue stars in the galaxy will be relatively low.